# How can I calculate a future date in google sheets when I know the number of months?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-dates

I have a date (TODAY()), and I have a number of months in a google sheet. How can I get a future date from this? I tried =DATE(TODAY()+MONTH(B63)). But the problem is that the months in B63 are not in date format, they are just an integer. So it can say 26 for example, or 3. How can I make this work? Can I make this work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function you need to use is the [`EDATE`](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092974?hl=en-GB)

```
=EDATE(TODAY(),J4)
```

[image]

Comment: Yes, works, thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Could you share a test sheet? From what it sounds like in your post this *should* be the answer, but it could be different.

I just did some research, and the function you're likely looking for is the

```
=EDATE()
```

function, which takes a date value and adds a set number of months.

```
=EDATE(TODAY(),B63)
```

Edit Note:
I removed the majority of my previous answer because it was overly complicated. This solution is far simpler.

Comment: This works perfectly, thank you!